# Cannot reconnect/clear out timed out sessions in spring boot websocket server backed with Jdbc and Postgres using java websocket client

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket, spring-session

I have issues in having sessions properly deleted in my stomp websocket server, when clients are closed or after long inactivity. I attempted with and without `spring session` but could not achieve the result. I will present here the version with spring session.

The client application, which implements a spring boot websocket stomp client, connects to the server, the http session is authenticated with basic authentication. Each user can have only one active connection. The security configuration follows the documentation for [concurrent sessions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#ns-concurrent-sessions)

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());

    http.sessionManagement(session -> session
            // allows only 1 valid session per user
            .maximumSessions(1)
            // and rejects the login if more than one session is attempted
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
    );

    return http.build();
  }

  @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
  private String driverclassname;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
  private String dataSourceUsername;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
  private String dataSourcePassword;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String dataSourceUrl;

  @Bean
  public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverclassname);
    dataSource.setUrl(dataSourceUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(dataSourceUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(dataSourcePassword);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsManager users(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager users = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    return users;
  }

}
```

Spring session is configured using spring boot in `application.properties`. It is backed by a Postgresql database as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/boot-jdbc.html). Session should time out in 1 minute.

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=1m
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-@@platform@@.sql
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
```

The server is configured as explained in spring boot documentation for what concerns [concurrent sessions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#ns-concurrent-sessions). It extends `AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` and injects a `HttpSessionEventPublisher` bean.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class EngineConfig extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<Session> {
  @Override
  public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
    registry.setMessageSizeLimit(WebSockProtocol.MESSAGE_SIZE_LIMIT);
    registry.setSendBufferSizeLimit(WebSockProtocol.SEND_BUFFER_SIZE_LIMIT);
    registry.setSendTimeLimit(WebSockProtocol.SEND_TIME_LIMIT);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint(WebSockProtocol.SRV_ENDPOINT);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker(WebSockProtocol.MSG_BROKER_PREFIX);
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(WebSockProtocol.APP_DESTINATION_PREFIX);
  }

  @Bean
  public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
  }
}
```

In my test scenario the client app connects to the server, I can see a new session in the Postgres database. If I shutdown the client, after 2 minutes the session is removed from the database, but the odd thing is that the client will never be able to re-connect again with the same user name. This tells me that the session is not properly cleared out after the expiration time.

Can somebody please explain me what am I doing wrong or how shall I modify the approach to have the sessions properly handled? Shall I back spring session with Redis?